# How to convert AC3 to Flac and apply a delay?

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, convert, flac

I have a MKV video file. The audio track is ac3. I extracted the AC3 and now want to convert it to Flac. But I need to add a delay/offset of 150ms. The offset should be permanent; the actual duration of the resulting Flac should be 150ms longer than the Ac3 input.

What is the command line to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it with **[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)** (Sound eXchange) and **ffmpeg** (or *avconv* instead of *ffmpeg*). SoX is *"the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation"*, an effects and audio manupilation & generation tool for the command line.

Install both:

```
sudo apt-get install sox ffmpeg
```

Convert your ac3 file to a wave file. Since SoX cannot read ac3 files directly, this step is unfortunately required:

```
ffmpeg -i sound.ac3 sound.wav
```

Use SoX with the *pad* switch to insert silence at the beginning:

```
sox sound.wav sound.flac pad 0.150
```

This inserts 150ms of silence at the beginning of the audio file.

Look at the [SoX Manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) for more infos.

You can also do this in a single line, without the need for creating an intermediate wav file, by using a pipe:

```
ffmpeg -i sound.ac3 -f wav - | sox - sound.flac pad 0.150
```

Answer (score 0):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/index.htm) should be able to handle that.

Do you want to remux the FLAC into the MKV? Otherwise I don't understand why you'd be concerned about the delay.

Comment: Only works with wine